# $_SESSION storing wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I made a portal where i have to fetch result with primary key as id i am using it everywhere storing it in a variable however there is a certain problem that i am facing

```
$sql="SELECT users from hostelusers WHERE users Like'%$roll%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $uid=$rows[0];
$_SESSION['uid']=$uid;
```

In  my code the variable $uid is echoing out values of column 1 ie users however I have selected column 0 which is id(in the table in mysql)

can't think of any mistake there

Comment: $sql="SELECT users from hostelusers WHERE users Like'%$roll%'";

Comment: run this query in your database directly. see what you get

Comment: what your users column of the db table have?

Answer (score 2):

your mysql query string is wrong . You are using :

```
$sql="SELECT users from hostelusers WHERE users Like'%$roll%'";
```

And how do you expect to get `id` field in the result ??

Moreover you will be having only a single column [field] in your `rows[]` and that is `rows[0]`

if you want to use `rows[0]` to get your `id` field

Change your query to this

```
$sql="SELECT id from hostelusers WHERE users Like'%$roll%'";
```

or this:

```
$sql="SELECT * from hostelusers WHERE users Like'%$roll%'";
```

and it will work for sure